# How can I deploy Elasticsearch cluster in Kubernete replicaset?

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes

I am trying to deploy Elasticsearch search to K8S cluster. Below is my configuration. It works fine for `replicas: 1`. But if I change it to a value more than 1 there will be multiple pods in the K8S cluster get deployed. But how can I make them working together as one Elasticsearch cluster nodes?

I know I can manually add the nodes in the Elasticsearch cluster by using the API. But is there any way to let the cluster discover the extra nodes automatically?

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: es
  namespace: default
spec:
  serviceName: es-entrypoint
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: es
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: es
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: es-config
          configMap:
            name: es-config
            items:
              - key: elasticsearch.yml
                path: elasticsearch.yml
        - name: persistent-storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: es-claim
      initContainers:
        - name: permissions-fix
          image: busybox
          volumeMounts:
            - name: persistent-storage
              mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
          command: [ 'chown' ]
          args: [ '1000:1000', '/usr/share/elasticsearch/data' ]
      containers:
        - name: es
          image: elasticsearch:7.10.1
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 2
              memory: 8
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 9200
            - containerPort: 9300
              name: inter-node
          volumeMounts:
            - name: es-config
              mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
              subPath: elasticsearch.yml
            - name: persistent-storage
              mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: es-entrypoint
spec:
  selector:
    name: es
  ports:
    - port: 9200
      targetPort: 9200
      protocol: TCP
  type: NodePort
```